# Keyboard not working with display

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, mouse

I have a MacBook Pro connected to a Thunderbolt Display.
In the display I have attached a mouse and an Apple keyboard. The keyboard works ok after it has been working but when I get to work and and plug in my laptop the keyboard is not responding. The funny thing is that the mouse always works and it is made from Microsoft. I have tested with 3 keyboards all having this problem. It's also funny that the keyboard works on the left usb on the MBP but not the right when this happens. This is the keyboard.
http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa?fnode=56

Anyone have an idea what can be causing this? Im using Mavericks on the MBP.

Comment: Sometimes it works

Comment: In other words, is the screen really related to the problem?

Comment: Maybe not. But its weird that the usb mouse always works but the keyboard not.